# ASP MVC 1.0 - Throwing 404 error from Controller so Web Crawlers will stop indexing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Having Issues trying to throw a 404 error page in MVC 1 from a Controller so that the page actually comes up as page not found. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How about returning HttpNotFoundResult() which was added in MVC3 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpnotfoundresult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: Due to being too busy with everything I'm still stuck using MVC 1 myself :T i'm going to try and implement CubeRoot's option in about an hour hopefully that will give me the desired result

Comment: ok, for MVC 1, that HttpNotFound suggested by CubeRoot and me are not available. But created your own, HttpNotFoundResult is simple, please see my example below.

Comment: You might want to consider returning a 410 as 404 implies that the resource may return in the future, if you really want the resource removed from the search engine then 410 is the one to use. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVC1, you may need to create your own HttpNotFoundResult like below and return that from your controller.

```
public class HttpNotFoundResult : ActionResult {
    public HttpNotFoundResult() {

    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }
}
```

In your action method, you can do.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
```

From MVC3, you can return HttpNotFound() result directly.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Comment: govin i extremely appreciate you trying to help me create one since it doesn't exist in MVC1... However I am running into a small issue.  Where do i put the class you created? I initially just created a New Class File all together and tried to implement it that way... But when i try to call it from within the controller it gives me an error saying "HttpNotFoundResult' is a type and cannot be used as an expression."

Comment: I've tried a few times to get this to work and I'm not having any luck. All I keep getting are errors

Comment: @MattHam - `return new HttpNotFoundResult();` x is a type and cannot be used should have been your clue to use the `new` keyword.

Comment: Right, I missed the new operator. HttpNotFoundResult is a class and has to be instantiated before it can be returned. Fixed the answer now,

Comment: That stopped it from erroring, but all it returns is a blank page with no data or anything.  Doesn't throw a 404 error page.

Comment: This actually does work.. When having it ran "locally" it throws a blank page because its not an actual "server" running to throw the 404 error.  After uploading the fixed changes, it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some logic that if your database doesn't return content then return HttpNotFound(); Additionally you can pass a string HttpNotFound("Maybe I deleted it?"); This is very similar to how the WebAPI works.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```